# Understanding Bounties

Tags: discussion, support

I've had two answers to feature bounties accepted here very recently, but now I'm puzzled to how they actually work.
Both had the "+50" icon next to them, so I assumed the correct answer would get 50 points...neither have done that. Both actually only awarded 25.
Since it happened twice, I'm assuming that I'm missing something from the equation, and now find myself posting this question.
What reason(s) could be behind not getting the full amount? I am aware the amount of points are up to the poster's discretion, however, I thought that once a solution was accepted, said points went from poster's profile, to answerer's profile.
Again, I'm pretty sure I'm missing a large piece of this puzzle, any help to clear up the confusion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the community wiki on the main Meta site about bounties

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/254520

I think this part is relevant to your question:

> **What is automatic awarding?**
>
> Approximately 24 hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be awarded automatically.
>
> If the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the bounty (provided that the answer was posted during the bounty period). Answers accepted before the bounty period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.
>
> Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be eligible are:
>
> The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
>
> The answer must have a score of at least +2
>
> The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.
>
> If neither of these conditions apply, the bounty is not awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

Comment: thanks phil. not just for the response but all the hard work you put in here. if you ever want to coordinate or chat i hope you won't hesitate to ping me. i sincerely appreciate all that you do.

Comment: just having fun :)

Comment: me too! what a time to be alive